# remove invalid chars from html document

Tags: php, html, regex, non-ascii-characters

i have a bunch of files which are supposed to be html documents for the most part, however sometimes the editor(s) copy&pasted text from other sources into it, so now i come across some weird chars every now and then - for example non-encoded copyright sign, or weird things that look like a dash or minus but are something else (ascii #146?), or a single char that looks like "...".
i had a look at get_html_translation_table(), however this will only replace the "usual" special chars like &, euro signs etc., but it seems like i need regex and specify only allowed chars and discard all the unknown chars. I tried this here, but this didnt work at all:

```
function fixNpChars($string)
{
    //characters in the hexadecimal ranges 00–08, 0B–0C, 0E–1F, 7F, and 80–9F cannot be used in an HTML document, not even by reference.
    $pattern = '/[\x{0000}-\x{0008}][\x{000B}-\x{000C}][\x{000E}-\x{001F}][\x{0080}-\x{009F}][x{007F}]/u';
    $replacement = '';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);   
}
```

Any idea whats wrong here?

EDIT:

The database where i store my imported files and the php side is all set to utf-8 (content type utf-8, db table charset utf8/utf8_general_ci, mysql_set_charset('utf8',$this->mHandle); executed after db connection is established. Most of the imported files are either utf8 or iso-8859-1.

Comment: looks to me like str_replace will be a simpler, better and more readable choice here, although I too like to use the Scorpion in Halo to kill the grunts, it is fun.

Comment: The single char that looks like "..." is called an ellipsis `…/&hellip;` and shouldnt pose a problem in an HTML document whatsoever when using utf-8. Chances are, you are doing something wrong. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex syntax looks a little problematic. Maybe this?:

`$pattern = '/[\x00-\x08][\x0B-\x0C][\x0E-\x1F][\x80-\x9F][x7F]/u';`

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of removing the invalid characters as the best option, this problem can be solved using `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode` functions.

Comment: From what i have read, some chars are not allowed in html, not even by reference (see the comment in my code). 
i cannot use htmlentities because it is already html-text for the most part, doing so would turn all < and > into &gt; and &lt; and breaking it.